# Inserting a panel between 2 controls in Windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to insert a Panel (User Control) dynamically between two other control. Let say I have a PictureBox(Control) as the parent are there is an other control on the pictureBox.

I want to remove the other control from the picture box, add a panel(control) to the picture box and then set the older control to the new panel. For now I have this code :

```
   If m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.HasChildren Then
     For Each child As Control In m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.Controls
        If (child.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Transparent) Then

           Dim panel As SXFadeWrapperForGPU = New SXFadeWrapperForGPU()
           panel.ClientSize = New Size(child.ClientSize.Width, child.ClientSize.Height)
           panel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(child.Location.X, child.Location.Y)
           m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.Controls.Add(panel)

           panel.Controls.Add(child)
           m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.Controls.Remove(child)
           AddHandler panel.Paint, AddressOf PanelPaintEvent
        End If
     Next
  End If
```

My code is adding a background wrapper to the transparent color  child in front of it. The thing is even if I remove the child before adding or after adding it back, I can never see it on the screen. Is there any particular thing that maybe the Remove does so the removed Child isn't usable again ?

Comment: This isn't c# its vb as far as I can tell

Comment: ..This code is not c#? Seems to be VB?

Comment: oops totally my bad, i'll edit that

Comment: You shouldn't modify the collection as you for-each through it.  You only have one instance of the "child" control, so once you add it to the panel, it automatically gets removed from the PictureBox control collection.  It's pretty confusing what you are trying to do with all this adding / removing stuff.

Comment: Ok so let's say I have control1 that contains control2. I want to add a new control3, but I want the hierarchy to be that control1 contains control3 that contains control2. I don't want the control1 to directly contains control2  anymore. I am not sure if this is even doable, this is why I'm asking.

Comment: You should change the `child` location to (0, 0), else it will still be relative to its position inside `MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox`, but now it's in the new panel. It could be there, just located outside the panel's boundary.

Comment: So I just try setting it's position and I also reset child.Visible to True and child.Enabled to True. Now i can get like 1 frame of the child visible and after that it is gone.

Comment: I'd say you have another issue totally unrelated to this question.

Comment: In fact you are, right, while debugging, I realize there was somewhere else in the code that was reseting the child Location, so I just changed that and now it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the child location to (0, 0), else it will still be relative to its position inside MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox, but now it's in the new panel. It could be there, just located outside the panel's boundary

```
If m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.HasChildren Then
    For Each child As Control In m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.Controls
        If (child.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Transparent) Then

            Dim panel As SXFadeWrapperForGPU = New SXFadeWrapperForGPU()
            panel.ClientSize = New Size(child.ClientSize.Width, child.ClientSize.Height)
            panel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(child.Location.X, child.Location.Y)
            m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.Controls.Add(panel)

            panel.Controls.Add(child)
            child.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0) ' <--- this
            m_targetDisplay.MainDoubleBufferedPictureBox.Controls.Remove(child)
            AddHandler panel.Paint, AddressOf PanelPaintEvent
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks ! Would have take so long to figured out that was the problem by myself !

Comment: That's why we're here :)